# How to translate this selection into CSS?

Tags: css

I have a `div` inside which there can be any tags. 
For example `p, span, h1, h4`...etc

Few tags like `p` and `h1` have default margins.

I want to write CSS which says

> Select the first immediate child of `div`

For example if the `div` contained only `p` tags, I could've written something like -

```
div > p:first-child {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

But here the case is that instead of `p`, it can be anything. How can I do it?

Comment: Just omit the tag name. `div > :first-child`

Answer (score 4):

> Select the first immediate child of div.

Both of these will work.

```
div > :first-child {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

or

```
div > *:first-child {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
div > :first-child {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

Hope it will work for you !